# Table output - For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I am trying to obtain a table with the all the values calculated inside the for loop. I checked the length of each of d6-d10 length and it is 35, the same as the length of "ou". I am able to store each of these values as vectors. "ou" in this case are country names like Angola, Botswana etc..

```
ou<- sort(unique(vldata$OperatingUnit)
for (i in ou) {
d6 <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_CURR" & vldata$OperatingUnit==i],na.rm = TRUE)
d7 <- sum(vldata$FY2016Q2[vldata$indicator=="TX_CURR" & vldata$OperatingUnit==i],na.rm = TRUE)
d8 <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$numeratorDenom=="D" & vldata$OperatingUnit==i], na.rm = TRUE)
d9 <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$numeratorDenom=="N" & vldata$OperatingUnit==i], na.rm = TRUE )
d10 <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$categoryOptionComboName=="Undetectable" & 
                            vldata$OperatingUnit==i], na.rm = TRUE)

dash1.table <- table(vldata$OperatingUnit,d6, d7, d8, d9, d10)
}
```

Error: `Error in table(vldata$OperatingUnit, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, : 
  all arguments must have the same length`

```
> str(ou)
List of 1
$ : Factor w/ 35 levels "Angola","Asia Regional Program",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

str(vldata$OperatingUnit)
Factor w/ 35 levels "Angola","Asia Regional Program",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

After running the loop, I get:

```
str(i)
Factor w/ 35 levels "Angola","Asia Regional Program",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

30 sample rows from my data (>200k rows). You can use UIDAll as the Operating Unit name or country name.

```
structure(list(UIDAll = structure(c(4L, 19L, 30L, 21L, 12L, 1L, 
24L, 20L, 9L, 22L, 13L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 29L, 7L, 18L, 25L, 15L, 
2L, 23L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 10L, 27L, 26L, 28L), .Label = c("a7kj6yR3FRT", 
"a9b2mJ4Z5Kv", "bcYTjHaZcE4", "CVAHCZfm5MK", "d507u4dhfug", "dBBdk4e1xGM", 
"h54eHtqrMYc", "h5siIA7lQfx", "Hk6QKCvBV9B", "I3Pvb7ryppf", "IrB4tyQKF5E", 
"JgEjEEV5Nsy", "JKnoiKiTSgm", "loiaqD14rjG", "mtHydPyChpG", "nPh5JYQQyqa", 
"oWG1PMWA3N1", "QDkCAOGVng6", "QZwDp4lHXWp", "rV9MIblAWIF", "s6HYTxvqhzX", 
"sNi4VZ2HDoT", "WGkhTclMK4U", "wZsEzdJHKVJ", "XME74MPBxXl", "Y63LmT4BKqS", 
"ycP81nJei2m", "yhnSeJ5NaC2", "yqGgSdD5hP3", "Z4XPx6jaeFf"), class = "factor"), 
indicator = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("TX_CURR", "TX_UNDETECT", 
"TX_VIRAL"), class = "factor"), numeratorDenom = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("D", 
"N"), class = "factor"), categoryOptionComboName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("default", 
"Detectable", "Routine", "Targeted", "Undetectable"), class = "factor"), 
FY2016Q2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 764L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FY2016Q4 = c(71L, NA, NA, NA, 43L, NA, 
844L, 2130L, NA, 0L, -9L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 643L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 48L, NA, 889L, NA, 89L, 651L, NA, 115L), FY2016APR = c(71L, 
NA, NA, NA, 43L, NA, 844L, 2130L, NA, 0L, -9L, 0L, NA, NA, 
0L, NA, NA, 643L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48L, NA, 889L, NA, 89L, 
651L, NA, 115L)), .Names = c("UIDAll", "indicator", "numeratorDenom", 
"categoryOptionComboName", "FY2016Q2", "FY2016Q4", "FY2016APR"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here `ou` is `list(vldata$UIDALL)`

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks, I have added subset of data

Comment: this is a sample of `vldata`, so `ou` will be `list(vldata$UIDALL)`. I see there is inconsistency in names. I have corrected that.

Comment: In the code you have `OperatingUnit`. I take it we should replace that with `UIDALL` right?

Comment: Yes, Operating Unit = UIDAll. I can't share the actual operating unit names in the data

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I think I understand what result you wanted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is how you're using the `table()` function.

`table()` displays the frequency of each level of an input vector. It you give it more than one vector of equal length then it creates a cross-table. However, the result of `sum()` is a scalar.

Your call to `table()` has a vector mixed with several scalars in each iteration. This won't work.

I think this is what you wanted:

```
dash1.table <- data.frame(ou = ou, d6=NA, d7 = NA, d8=NA, d9=NA, d10=NA)

for (i in ou) {
  dash1.table$d6[dash1.table$ou==i] <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_CURR" & vldata$UIDAll==i],na.rm = TRUE)
  dash1.table$d7[dash1.table$ou==i] <- sum(vldata$FY2016Q2[vldata$indicator=="TX_CURR" & vldata$UIDAll==i],na.rm = TRUE)
  dash1.table$d8[dash1.table$ou==i] <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$numeratorDenom=="D" & vldata$UIDAll==i], na.rm = TRUE)
  dash1.table$d9[dash1.table$ou==i] <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$numeratorDenom=="N" & vldata$UIDAll==i], na.rm = TRUE )
  dash1.table$d10[dash1.table$ou==i] <- sum(vldata$FY2016APR[vldata$indicator=="TX_VIRAL" & vldata$categoryOptionComboName=="Undetectable" & 
                                vldata$UIDAll==i], na.rm = TRUE)


}

dash1.table
```

> ```
>             ou  d6  d7 d8  d9 d10
> 1  CVAHCZfm5MK   0   0  0   0   0
> 2  QZwDp4lHXWp   0   0  0   0   0
> 3  Z4XPx6jaeFf   0   0  0   0   0
> 4  s6HYTxvqhzX   0   0  0   0   0
> 5  JgEjEEV5Nsy   0   0 43   0   0
> 6  a7kj6yR3FRT   0   0  0   0   0
> 7  wZsEzdJHKVJ   0   0  0 844 844
> 8  rV9MIblAWIF   0   0  0   0   0
> 9  Hk6QKCvBV9B   0   0  0   0   0
> 10 sNi4VZ2HDoT   0   0  0   0   0
> 11 JKnoiKiTSgm   0   0  0   0   0
> 12 h5siIA7lQfx   0   0  0   0   0
> 13 bcYTjHaZcE4   0   0  0   0   0
> 14 dBBdk4e1xGM   0   0  0   0   0
> 15 d507u4dhfug   0   0  0   0   0
> 16 yqGgSdD5hP3   0   0  0   0   0
> 17 h54eHtqrMYc   0   0  0   0   0
> 18 QDkCAOGVng6 643 764  0   0   0
> 19 XME74MPBxXl   0   0  0   0   0
> 20 mtHydPyChpG   0   0  0   0   0
> 21 a9b2mJ4Z5Kv   0   0  0   0   0
> 22 WGkhTclMK4U   0   0  0   0   0
> 23 IrB4tyQKF5E   0   0  0   0   0
> 24 loiaqD14rjG   0   0  0   0   0
> 25 oWG1PMWA3N1   0   0  0   0   0
> 26 nPh5JYQQyqa   0   0  0   0   0
> 27 I3Pvb7ryppf   0   0  0   0   0
> 28 ycP81nJei2m   0   0  0   0   0
> 29 Y63LmT4BKqS   0   0  0   0   0
> 30 yhnSeJ5NaC2   0   0  0   0   0
> ```

Note that since this is only a sample of data for the example, there are many 0's.

Comment: Oh but now it populates the table with exactly the same data for each country. Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: @anubhutimishra For each level of `ou` you're getting the same result? This should not be the case. In each iteration you're only replacing values for that level of `ou`. Something must have happened when you were transitioning the code from this example to your real data. Let me show you the example result so that you can see what I mean. The results are different for all of the non-zero levels (and I presume there are only so many 0's due to sampling the data).  If this doesn't resolve the problem can you please update the question so that I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I see that I made some error in changing my code. Corrected and now it works. Thanks

Comment: No problem! Cheers